# Syntax error: redirection unexpected

Tags: shell

I run the following script but i'm getting syntax error : redirection unexpected

```
#!/bin/sh

# Bash strict mode, stop on any error
set -euo pipefail

# Ensure all required environment variables are present
test -n "$DATABRICKS_WORKSPACE_RESOURCE_ID"
test -n "$KEY_VAULT"
test -n "$SECRET_NAME"
test -n "$ARM_CLIENT_ID"
test -n "$ARM_CLIENT_SECRET"
test -n "$ARM_TENANT_ID"

# Login
az login --service-principal -u "$ARM_CLIENT_ID" -p "$ARM_CLIENT_SECRET" -t "$ARM_TENANT_ID"

# Get a token for the global Databricks application.
# The resource name is fixed and never changes.
token_response=$(az account get-access-token --resource 2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d)
token=$(jq .accessToken -r <<< "$token_response")

# Get a token for the Azure management API
token_response=$(az account get-access-token --resource https://management.core.windows.net/)
azToken=$(jq .accessToken -r <<< "$token_response")

# Generate a PAT token. Note the quota limit of 600 tokens.
api_response=$(curl -sf $DATABRICKS_ENDPOINT/api/2.0/token/create \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
  -H "X-Databricks-Azure-SP-Management-Token:$azToken" \
  -H "X-Databricks-Azure-Workspace-Resource-Id:$DATABRICKS_WORKSPACE_RESOURCE_ID" \
  -d '{ "comment": "Terraform-generated token" }')
pat_token=$(jq .token_value -r <<< "$api_response")

az keyvault secret set --vault-name "$KEY_VAULT" -n "$SECRET_NAME" --value "$pat_token"
```

any idea how can I get it to work ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here strings like `<<< "$token_response"` are not supported by POSIX `/bin/sh`

Either switch to a shell that supports them such as `/bin/bash`, or modify your command to something like

```
pat_token=$(printf '%s\n' "$api_response" | jq .token_value -r)
```